# Como transformar uma matriz de um ÚNICO objeto?

Tags: javascript, ionic, typescript, ionic3

A minha dúvida é a seguinte, como eu posso fazer com que uma matriz que tenha 3 objetos, se transforme em um único objeto ? Conforme o print abaixo, a matriz está me trazendo 3 objetos, porém eu preciso montar um único objeto com o valor de cada matriz, já pesquisei algo como reduce, mas não consegui obter sucesso. Aqui está o meu código :

```
       //"ITEMS" é um FirebaseListObservable que transformo em um array
       //javascript

       //dadosPontoFuncionario é o meu array javascript, que está retornando
       //o que está no console, é ele que preciso que vire um único objeto

       this.items.subscribe( data => {
         this.dadosPontoFuncionario = data;
         console.log(this.dadosPontoFuncionario);
       })
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Que matriz? você não tem um array de objetos?

Comment: Como você vai tratar se houverem duas chaves iguais ao juntar os objetos do seu array?

Comment: Tenho um array de objetos, porém eu gostaria de transformá-lo em um único objeto entende, unir os 3 objetos em um só, na verdade nem sei se tem como fazer isso.

Depende qual chave ele considera, a $key é única, porém eu tenho outros dois tipos de chaves que são repetidos em cada objeto desse.

Comment: Ainda não consegui entender... você gerar um único objeto consolidando todas as proprieades de todos os objetos do array? ou criar um a réplica em um único objeto onde cada objeto seria uma propriedade? Ex.: `{ item1: {}, item2:{} ...}`

Comment: Gerar um único objeto consolidando todas as propriedades de todos os objetos do array. Para você entender melhor, é uma aplicação de registro de ponto. Então cada objeto corresponde a um ponto registrado, tenho o ponto de inicio, ponto do intervalo, ponto do fim do expediente. Preciso mostra-los na tela para o usuário, porém para organizar melhor, eu queria unir os 3 objetos, assim eu posso ter acesso a informação dos 3 ao mesmo tempo e posso mostrar essas informações na tela. Se não eu tenho que mostrar os objetos separados na view.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi direito, mas vou tentar...

Se for o que estou imaginando,

```js
const arrayObject = [
{nome:'Objeto um'},
{teste:'Objeto dois'},
{nome:'Objeto tres'}
]

console.log(arrayObject.reduce((a,b)=>({...a, ...b})))
```

você pode fazer um reduce, o problema é que se os objetos tiverem chaves com o mesmo nome valerá o valor da chave do úlimo objeto encontrado..

Comment: Exatamente, eu cheguei ao mesmo resultado do seu código. Porém tem esse problema das chaves. Nesse listObservable, eu tenho um campo que é repetido nos 3 objetos, pois eu preciso dele para consulta do banco de dados. Acho que vou ter que arrumar outra forma de fazer...

Comment: Pois o idEmpresa e o empresaKey eu utilizo para comparar se o funcionário pertence a aquela empresa ou não, já que se trata de uma aplicação multiusuário, vou ter que ver outra forma de fazer eu acho. Mas fico agradecido pela sua resposta